# UNITY + PHOTON Sync scene unity in photon cloud

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

How can I synchronize scenes of all players according to the first player who created the room?

Specifically. The items will be randomly generated on the creator's scene. All guests entering the room will sync.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom room properties for that, where you define all these random elements final state, and players joining the room, will read these custom properties and reproduce these elements as described in the room properties. Players currently in the room can listen to room property change callback and adjust realtime.

doc: https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/v2/gameplay/synchronization-and-state#custom_properties